# Call the column of a data frame by position using group_by function in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, time, dplyr

I want to calculate the monthly mean values in each year for daily streamflow data. I am using the functions `group_by` and `summarize` for this purpose.

This is my input:
[image]

and this is my code:

```
x[[1]] %>% group_by(year, month) %>% summarize(mean.value = mean(x[[1]][[2]]))
```

I believe my problem is when I calculate the mean value of the second column of the data frame (`DailyPrec`)using the `mean` function.

The output I got is:
[image]

when I do using the column name:

```
x[[1]] %>% group_by(year, month) %>% summarize(mean.value = mean(DailyPrec))
```

it works, and I got the output:

[image]

However, I do not want to indicate the column name, I want to do it referring to the column position, in the case, the second column.

How is possible to call to the second column of the data frame without using the name of the column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use a couple of options i.e. get the `names` of the data with the corresponding index, convert to `sym`bol and evaluate (`!!`)

```
library(dplyr)
x[[1]] %>%
    group_by(year, month) %>% 
    summarize(mean.value = mean(!! rlang::sym(names(x[[1]])[2])))
```

---

Or another option is `across` which can either take an index or column name (quoted or unquoted).

```
x[[1]] %>%
    group_by(year, month) %>% 
    summarize(across(all_of(names(x[[1]])[2]), mean, na.rm = TRUE))
```

---

Also, the above code seems to be using a sequence to loop over the `list`.  Instead, we could use `lapply/map` to loop over each element of the `list` i.e

```
library(purrr)
map(x, ~ .x %>%
          group_by(year, month) %>%
          summarise(across(2, mean, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

---

The issue in calling the `x[[1]][[2]]` in the `mean` is that it extracts the whole column breaking the `group_by` attribute previously created and thus the OP got the same value as `mean` for each group i.e. the `mean` of the whole data